# Numpy Array bug

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array

```
array = [np.array([[0.76103773], [0.12167502]]),
         np.array([[ 0.72017135,  0.1633635 ,  0.39956811,  0.91484082, 0.76242736, -0.39897202],
                  [0.38787197, -0.06179132, -0.04213892,  0.16762614,  0.05880554, 0.59370467]])]
```

And I want to convert it into a numpy object array that contains numpy ndarrays. So I tried, `np.array(array)`, `np.array(array, dtype=object)`,`np.array(array, dtype=np.object)`
But all of them give the same error, `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,1) into shape (2)`. So basically, the end result should be the same, just that the type of the end result is a numpy object array, not a python list. Can anyone help?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, do you just want to [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)? Or possibly just add a new axis: `array[:, :, None]`? Oh wait, are you trying to put arrays of different sizes into a parent array? You can't do that, use a list instead.

Comment: I just want the same list but, instead of a list, I want a numpy object array containing the same elements @Dan

Comment: Why do you want that? Why is a list not good enough? It will help if you explain the end goal. I'm pretty certain that you can't put different sized arrays into the elements of another array the way you can with lists. That's not the purpose of arrays.

Comment: @Dan In the end I want to do `array1-array2` where they both are numpy object arrays but the respective elements have the same shape, and i subtract the arrays each other. I can do this using list comprehension, but doing it this way seems neater.

Comment: list comprehension is the way to go here, you can't do that with an array unless you are willing to pad it. Arrays must be hyper-rectangular in shape. Think about what `arr.shape` would return for the case you are describing, it wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list contains (2,1) and (2,6) shaped arrays.

`np.array` tries to create a multidimensional array from the inputs.  That works fine with inputs that have matching shapes (or length and nesting).  Failing that it falls back on creating object dtype arrays.

But in cases where the first dimensions of the input arrays match is produces this kind of error.  Evidently it has initialed an 'blank' array, and is trying to copy the list arrays into it.  I haven't looked at the details, but I've seen the error message before.

In effect giving `np.array` an list of diverse size arrays, forces it to use some backup methods.  So produce an object array, others produce this kind of error.  If your list contained arrays all the same shape, the result would be a 3d array, not an object array.

The surest way to make a object array with given shape, is to initialize it, and then copy from the list.

```
In [66]: alist =[np.array([[0.76103773], [0.12167502]]), 
    ...:          np.array([[ 0.72017135,  0.1633635 ,  0.39956811,  0.91484082, 0.76242736, -0.39897202], 
    ...:                   [0.38787197, -0.06179132, -0.04213892,  0.16762614,  0.05880554, 0.59370467]])]   
In [67]: alist[0].shape                                                                                      
Out[67]: (2, 1)
In [68]: alist[1].shape                                                                                      
Out[68]: (2, 6)
In [69]: np.array(alist, object)                                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-261e1ad7e5cc> in <module>
----> 1 np.array(alist, object)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,1) into shape (2)
In [70]: arr = np.zeros(2, object)                                                                           
In [71]: arr[:] = alist                                                                                      
In [72]: arr                                                                                                 
Out[72]: 
array([array([[0.76103773],
       [0.12167502]]),
       array([[ 0.72017135,  0.1633635 ,  0.39956811,  0.91484082,  0.76242736,
        -0.39897202],
       [ 0.38787197, -0.06179132, -0.04213892,  0.16762614,  0.05880554,
         0.59370467]])], dtype=object)
```

---

Don't expect too much from object dtype arrays.  Math is hit-or-miss.  Somethings work - if they can delegate the action to the elements.  Others don't work:

```
In [73]: arr - arr                                                                                           
Out[73]: 
array([array([[0.],
       [0.]]),
       array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])], dtype=object)
In [74]: np.log(arr)                                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-a67b4ae04e95> in <module>
----> 1 np.log(arr)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'log'
```

Even when the math works it isn't faster than a list comprehension.  In fact iteration on an object array is slower than iteration on a list.

Comment: but can't this be done without initializing? Like, in one line?

Comment: NO!  As you found out `np.array` makes the wrong guess as to to desired shape of the result.  It's fudging, and doesn't always get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

```
array1 =  np.array([[0.76103773], [0.12167502]])
array2 = np.array([[ 0.72017135,  0.1633635 ,  0.39956811,  0.91484082, 0.76242736, -0.39897202],[0.38787197, -0.06179132, -0.04213892,  0.16762614, 0.05880554, 0.59370467]])
result = np.hstack([array1,array2])
```

EDIT:
Maybe this?

```
array1 =  [[0.76103773], [0.12167502]]
array2 = [[ 0.72017135,  0.1633635 ,  0.39956811,  0.91484082, 0.76242736, -0.39897202],[0.38787197, -0.06179132, -0.04213892,  0.16762614,  0.05880554, 0.59370467]]
result = np.array([array1,array2])
```

EDIT 2:

Ok, Let's try one more time.  I think this is it.

```
array1 =  np.array([[0.76103773], [0.12167502]])
array2 = np.array([[ 0.72017135,  0.1633635 ,  0.39956811,  0.91484082, 0.76242736, -0.39897202],[0.38787197, -0.06179132, -0.04213892,  0.16762614,  0.05880554, 0.59370467]])
#solution is either
result = np.array([array1,array2.transpose()])
#or this 
result2 = np.array([array1.transpose(),array2])
```

Comment: no, i just want the same array but, a numpy object array

Comment: edit: no, the second method, gives me a numpy object array, but it is made of lists, not numpy nd arrays